# LibGDX - Unknown animation error

Tags: java, animation, 3d, libgdx, blender

I am developing an application on libgdx and I am trying to play an animation I created on Blender but I continue to get the unknown animation error. I have this code in my **create** method:

```java
model = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("i1.g3db", FileType.Internal));
modelInstance = new ModelInstance(model);
modelInstance.transform.rotate(1, 0, 0, -90);
modelInstance.transform.translate(0, 0, -2);
controller = new AnimationController(modelInstance);  
controller.setAnimation("moveHand",1);
```

And this in my **render** method:

```java
camera.update();
camController.update();
controller.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
modelBatch.begin(camera);
modelBatch.render(modelInstance, environment);
modelBatch.end();
```

I tried to cut out the pieces that are not relevant to the question. Here is a pic of the dopesheet in Blender which shows that I have named my animation appropriately:

[image]
Anyone has an idea what might be the problem cause I've been stuck on this one for quite a while, thank you! I have the animation files (.g3db, .blender) uploaded here if anyone feels like opening them:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xyx74tx5mbyj9i3/i1.zip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a general note: avoid using uppercase (and spaces etc.) in animation names. Also check https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/3D-animations-and-skinning for more information about animations and https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Importing-Blender-models-in-LibGDX for information about using Blender models in LibGDX.

Convert the file to .g3dj using the `-o G3DJ` command line option of `fbx-conv`, e.g. `fbx-conv -f -o G3DJ i1.fbx` (where `-f` is used to flip texture coordinates). Make sure to update your code to use this G3DJ file instead of the previous G3DB file. Next open the resulting .g3dj file using a text editor (e.g. notepad or the text editor of your ide/eclipse). The file should be easily readable (see http://blog.xoppa.com/behind-the-3d-scenes-part1/ for more info on how to read it) and contain a section (json key) called `animations`.

If there are no animations in the file, it should looks like `"animations": []` at the bottom of the file. In that case make sure to check to export animations in blender. See also: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Importing-Blender-models-in-LibGDX.

If there are animations in the file, they are included inside the array (between the `"animations": [` and `]`). Note that animations can take up a lot of space, so the actual line `"animations": [` might be located somewhere in the middle of the file. In that case make sure that the name (`id`) of the animation exactly matches the string used to specify the animation.

If the animation is included in the file and the string matches, then enumerate all animations inside the model/modelinstance to ensure they are correctly loaded:

```
for (Animation anim : modelInstance.animations)
    Gdx.app.log("Animation", anim.id);
```

If the animation is not included in the ModelInstance replace `modelInstance` with `model` in this snippet to make sure it is included in the model. If it also isn't included in the Model, make sure to refresh/clean your workspace.

Comment: Hi Xoppa, many thanks for your detailed response! I converted the model to g3dj and I can see the animation in the bottom of the file now. However, when I try running it I get a "Error parsing file: I_new.g3dj at  com.badlogic.gdx.utils.UBJsonReader.parse(UBJsonReader.java:47)" error; 

Should I use the same code to import the file as for the g3db before that?

Comment: If you don't use AssetManager (which I would advise you to use), you'll have to specify the JsonReader for G3DJ files (instead of UBJsonReader for G3DB files). So e.g. `new G3dModelLoader(new JsonReader(), resolver)`. See http://blog.xoppa.com/loading-models-using-libgdx/ on how to load using AssetManager.

Comment: I implemented the AssetManager at it is now showing the model but when I add the "controller.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());" line it returns a null pointer exception. I have the code over here:

http://pastebin.com/E5tL5dJy

Am I missing something?

Comment: Check if the controller isn't null, e.g. `if (controller != null) controller.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());`